# Why doesn't my object material show in Viewport shader?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, objects, 3d-view, object-mode

I am having trouble seeing my Boat Materials in Rendered Viewport Shader Mode. It is only showing in materials.[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]
Original project

[image]
Pack.Blend

[image]
Beige Wallpaper Jpg

[image]

Wood Wallpaper Jpg

[image]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file?

Comment: @moonboots I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: Use https://blend-exchange.com/ or workupload and share the link

Comment: Thank you, Link has been shared under posted photo. @moonboots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable its *Shadow Catcher* option:

[image]

Also be careful because some objects are disabled for preview but activated for render:

[image]

Also you need to plug the correct images into the *Principled BSDF* inputs, for example plug *wood_planks_dirt_diff.png* into the *Base Color*, you don't have any normal map here so replace the *Normal Map* node by a *Bump*  node and plug *wood_planks_dirt_diff_1k.jpg* into it (the *Image Texture* needs to be set to *Non-Color* and not *sRGB*), etc

Comment: Thank you for the tips! I’ve added another photo to the post with Shadow catcher disabled and objects showing visible. Only  in rendered viewport it is black. I was thinking to add a smart uv wrap to the material or try re-adding the object and material @moonboots

Comment: could you please pack your images and share your file again?

Comment: Hey, @moonboots I have shared my files again.

Comment: You haven't packed your image (File > External Data > Pack Resources)

Comment: Hey, @moonboots I hope that upload everything correctly. Above  Iv'e added in the Original File along with other blender files for the materials for the boat

Comment: your images are not correctly plugged and also you need to replace the Normal Map by a Bump node

Comment: Thank you, I also figured out the the Ray Visibility was set to Diffuse and needed to be turned off